# Delete object from array in MongoDB in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, bukkit

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ee227d69dba6729ca8938fc"
  },
  "uuid": "4e9be217-a2c7-490f-86b7-2d46a69980a3",
  "locks": {
    "furnace_1591879638": {
      "type": "FURNACE",
      "location": {
        "world": "world",
        "x": -33,
        "y": 73,
        "z": -227
      },
      "created": "Thu Jun 11 14:47:18 CEST 2020",
      "peopleWithAccess": []
    },
    "chest_1591903237541": {
      "type": "CHEST",
      "location": {
        "world": "world",
        "x": -36,
        "y": 73,
        "z": -224
      },
      "created": "Thu Jun 11 21:20:37 CEST 2020",
      "peopleWithAccess": []
    }
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ee2864622c67536a249fb0a"
  },
  "uuid": "6fc93f76-b03b-4af3-a679-ac53cafdb288",
  "locks": {}
}]
```

Hi,
I just stared with MongoDB and I was used to working with MySQL so this is really confusing for me. I've been trying to delete a object from an array but unsuccessfully. I tried this:

```
getMongoManager().getDatabase().getCollection("players").updateOne(new Document("uuid", player.getUniqueId().toString()),
                new Document("$unset", "locks." + id))
```

That gave me an error Modifiers operate on fields but we found type string instead.
How would I delete for exmaple object ***furnace_1591879638*** from player with uuid ***4e9be217-a2c7-490f-86b7-2d46a69980a3*** in Java?

Comment: There are some examples [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/getting-started/quick-start/).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, we cannot use the **$unset** operator to remove objects from an array, since the operator can only remove whole fields. For removing and inserting in an array, we are using **$pull** and **$push**.

I would recommend you to look up, both Bson [Updates](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/model/Updates.html) and [Filters](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html) class because they are making it way easier, instead of using the operators (At least for the mongodb driver version 3.8 or higher; I do not know if older versions support Bson).
With the help of these classes, you could extend your

> MongoManager

class and try something like this:

```
public void pullByFilter(String queryField, Object queryValue, String arrayName, Object value) {
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = getCollection("players");
    Bson update = Updates.pullByFilter(Filters.eq(arrayName, value));
    collection.updateOne(Filters.eq(queryField, queryValue), update);
}
```

This method should remove the specified value from the array.
Just for clearance: the *queryField* and *queryValue* parameters are used to identify the document (for you, the *queryField* should be "uuid" and the *queryValue* should be the players UUID as string).

Lastly, I think the method you tried with the **$unset** operator is giving you an error because you need to specify a new Document after the operator.
This:

```
getMongoManager().getDatabase().getCollection("players").updateOne(new Document("uuid", player.getUniqueId().toString()),
                new Document("$unset", "locks." + id))
```

should rather be:

```
getMongoManager().getDatabase().getCollection("players").updateOne(new Document("uuid", player.getUniqueId().toString()),
                new Document("$unset", new Document("locks", id)))
```

Also, a good tutorial for updating documents can be found [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-java-and-mongodb--update-operations?utm_campaign=updatejava&utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=organic_social).